# Acquire the list of available devices before starting Appium session

Tags: c#, android, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a remote machine with many iOS and Android devices connected to it through USB. My tests are executing on another machine and speaking to Appium server on that first machine. From my tests I'd like to obtain the list of available (connected to that machine) Android and iOS devices so that then I could start Appium session and begin my tests iterating over the devices. What I'd like Appium server to do, is execute `adb devices` for Android and `instrumets -s devices` for iOS and return this information to me. Can it do that? If no, what would be the best way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

yes indeed that looks like the right way to go.

You should then use the `deviceName` desired capability when connecting to the Appium server.

**WARNING**: the [documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?python#appium-server-capabilities) says that the `deviceName` desired capability is only available for iOS devices and is ignored for Android devices. The workaround is to set the desired device on Appiun start like this:

```
~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
30049e9795957100    device
HT449W900974    device

~$ appium -U 30049e9795957100
```

Comment: The tests (Appium client) and Appium (server) are running on different machines. I cannot access `adb` from the tests.

Comment: Then create an API between these two machines. This API can instruct the appium machine to restart the appium service and connect to a specific device.